# perl array only prints the last line

Tags: perl

I have a file of around 3000 lines. I am matching every word in the document against reference lists that i have. If the word matches to the one in my list then I substitute it.
The problem now is that the code only prints the last line, but not the entire file.

I am sure that my code is not that efficient and will take a long time to process, is there anyway to increase the efficiency of the code

```
open IN, "drug_list.txt" or die "No such file:$!\n";
open OUT, ">synergy1.txt" or die;
while(<IN>) {
      my @a=split /\t/,$_;
      $a[0]=~s/\s//g;
      $a[1]=~s/\s//g;
      $a[2]=~s/\s//g;
      $b[$i]=$a[0];
      $c[$i]=$a[1];
      $d[$i]=$a[2];
      ++$i;
}

use Data::Dumper;
open FILE, "input.txt" or die "No such file:$!\n";
while(<FILE>) {
    my $line= $_;
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/(\)|\()//g;
    $line =~ s/,/ ,/g;
    $line =~ s/\./ ./g;
    @array = split ' ',$line;

    for($k=0;$k<$i;++$k) {
        foreach $n(@array) {
            if($n=~m/^\Q$b[$k]\E$/i) {
                $n=~s/$n/<span style="background-color:yellow;">$n<\/span>/;
            }
            if($n=~m/^\Q$c[$k]\E$/i) {
                $n=~s/$n/<span style="background-color:red;">$n<\/span>/;
            }
            if($n=~m/^\Q$d[$k]\E$/i) {
                $n=~s/$n/<span style="background-color:blue;">$n<\/span>/;
            }
         }  # end foreach
     }      # end for
}           # end while
print OUT "@array";
close(FILE);
close(IN);
```

Comment: Your indentation is horrible. You should fix that, so that you can read your own code.

Comment: I fixed it for you. Now it is rather easy to spot your problem: Your statement `print OUT "@array"` is outside the loop, hence it only prints the last line assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create two variables named `@array`.

```
my @array;
while(<IN>) 
 {
  ...
  my @array = split ' ',$line;
```

Comment: @Pink That's because you set `@array = split ' ', $line` each loop iteration. Seems pretty basic to me. If you were to do `for (0 .. 10) { $num = $_ } print "$num"` you would not expect it to print `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, right? It prints the last value you set it to, not all the values it has been set to in the past. If you were to place the print statement *inside* the loop, it might work better.

Answer (score 3):

> I have edited the code, now only the last line get printed

Now you are re-assigning to `@array` at each pass:

```
 while(<FILE>) 
  { 

[...]

    @array = split ' ',$line;

[...]

  }

  print OUT "@array";
```

When array gets printed out, it only contains the last line.  The easiest solution is probably to move the `print OUT` line to *inside* the `while()` loop, right at the end.  This way it will get printed out *before* it gets reassigned the contents of a new line.

Comment: @Pink: Put the `print OUT "$array";` one line up, so it is above `}           # end while`

Answer (score 1):

Also you `close(IN)` and a few lines later you try to do `while (<IN>)`.

Please provide working code and example data. Otherwise it will be a tough job figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited the code, it was a mistake. The code is the one that I have posted and a detailed explanation would be that I am checking every word of my file against three reference lists that i have. The three list in the above code are in the first while loop.$b[$i], $c[$i] and $d[$i] are the example of the list. The second while loop is the file.... Hope this helps